# Angular2 check if one of the form controls is in focus

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In Angular2 app, I have a form ("FormGroup").

The form has a few forms on it.

```
this.mainForm = this.fb.group({
       firstPart:this.firstForm,
       secondPart:this.secondForm,
       thirdPart:this.thirdForm
       ....
});
```

My requirment is, in some place in my code I need to check if a form (not the main form, but some of the inner forms) is in focus.

Actually I need something like this.:

```
isFormInFocus(formName) {
   let innerForm = this.mainForm.controls[formName];
   //NOT EXIST - I need something like this...
   return innerForm.focus;
}
```

My issue is I don't find how to check this even to a specific form control.

if I will know this, I can, as a workaround, loop all form controls in the inner form and check if one of them is in focus...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar need.  I didn't see any valid properties off the form control either.  I then pulled in a `ViewChild` reference with an `Input` or `ElementRef` to get the actual `<input>` in my case.  Again I found no property for focus that I could use.

So, unfortunately I was left keeping track of the focus state myself (which seems crazy).  It works well, just seems like overkill.

**HTML**

```
<input md-no-float placeholder="City or Zip" type="text" matInput formControlName="destination" (focus)="autocompleteFocus()" (blur)="autocompleteBlur()">
```

**TS**

```
isDestinationFocused: boolean;

autocompleteFocus() {
    this.isDestinationFocused = true;
}

autocompleteBlur() {    
    this.isDestinationFocused = false;
}
```